# Fontspec & Newcommand: Add parameter to \newfontfamily

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontfamily

I need help with defining an alias to a `\newfontfamily` command.

**What I need** is something very similar to `\textbf{aaa}`, but with the command for a font family, ex. `\Courier{aaa}`, such that only the parameter is in the desired font.

Something like `\newfontfamily{\Courier}{Courier{#1}`. That would be invalid syntax, of course, since the second parameter isn't a command, but you get the idea.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%% FONTSPEC %%%
\defaultfontfeatures[CourierPrime]{
    Extension={.ttf},
    UprightFont={*-Regular},
    BoldFont={*-Bold},
    ItalicFont={*-Italic},
    BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic},
}

\newfontfamily{\Courier}%
    {CourierPrime}
    \newcommand{\cp}{\Courier}

\begin{document}

\cp{This text shall be in Courier Prime}, while this shall not.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the phrase after the comma is still in the Courier font:

[image: As visible, the phrase after the comma is, infact, still in the Courier font.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX has `\DeclareTextFontCommand` to declare commands like `\textbf` when you already have a switch like `\bfseries` (or in your case `\Courier`). It can be used as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%% FONTSPEC %%%
\defaultfontfeatures[CourierPrime]{
    Extension={.ttf},
    UprightFont={*-Regular},
    BoldFont={*-Bold},
    ItalicFont={*-Italic},
    BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic},
}

\newfontfamily{\Courier}%
    {CourierPrime}
\DeclareTextFontCommand \textcourier \Courier

\begin{document}

\textcourier{This text shall be in Courier Prime}, while this shall not.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's my mistake, thank you.

Comment: It could be an addition to `fontspec`: after defining `\Courier`, the package could also define `\textCourier` by default or a different name specified in the options.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/435